# Clarifying Java's evolutionary support of Unicode

Tags: java, string, unicode, unicode-string

I'm finding Java's differentiation of char and codepoint to be strange and out of place.

For example, a string is an array of characters or "letters which appear in an alphabet"; in contrast to codepoint which MAY be a single letter or possibly a composite or surrogate pair. However, Java defines a character of a string as a `char` which cannot be composite or contain a surrogate the codepoint and as an `int` (this is fine).

But then `length()` seems to return the number of codepoints while `codePointCount()` also returns the number of codepoints but instead combines composite characters.. which ends up not really being the real count of codepoints?

It feels as though `charAt()` should return a `String` so that composites and surrogates are brought along and the result of `length()` should swap with `codePointCount()`.

The original implementation feels a little backwards. Is there a reason for the way it's designed the way it is?

**Update: `codePointAt()`, `codePointBefore()`**

It's also worth noting that `codePointAt()` and `codePointBefore()` accept an index as a parameter, however, the index acts upon chars and has a range of `0` to `length() - 1` and is therefore not based on the number of codepoints in the string, as one might assume.

**Update: `equalsIgnoreCase()`**

String.equalsIgnoreCase() uses the term `normalization` to describe what it does prior to comparing strings. This is a misnomer as normalization in the context of a Unicode string can mean something entirely different. What they mean to say is that they use case-folding.

Comment: Unicode's grown warts on its warts since Java 1.0?

Comment: You're right. A little bit more searching provided this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174947/why-does-java-use-utf-16-for-internal-string-representation?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: worth to note that you read the API wrong for `But then length() seems to return the number of codepoints `.  From JDK7 API, it says ` The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string`.  Note that it is "Unicode code units" instead of "codepoints"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When java was created Unicode didn't have the notion of surrogate characters and java decided to represent characters as 16bit values.

I suppose they don't want to break backwards compatibility.  There is a lot more information here:  http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html