# Win32 Unicode normalization pre-Vista

Tags: winapi, unicode

I'm looking into the various normalization methods in regards to a case insensitive comparison of strings.

The most historically compatible method I've come up with is to call `FoldString()` with `MAP_PRECOMPOSED` to precompose each string and then call `CharUpper()` and then `CharLower()` on it to complete the normalization. This seems to be how Java does it (minus the precomposition).

There are libraries such as ICU but I would like to keep my Unicode handling as lightweight as possible by relying on the APIs provided by the operating system instead of adding a large dependency.

I am aware that this uses the current system locale by default. I believe I read somewhere that Java uses en-US by default when performing `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Thoughts?

Comment: [NormalizeString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093.aspx) is available for Windows XP SP2, and Windows Server 2003 as a redistributable package (see [Microsoft Internationalized Domain Names (IDN) Mitigation APIs 1.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=734)).

Comment: Unicode case folding and normalization forms like NFC are different things. I think your question would be a lot clearer and you'd get better answers if you substituted "normalization" with "case folding".

Comment: I used the word "normalization" because this is how the JDK described it. While researching this further I now realize that this was merely a different semantic use of the word normalization; they go on to define that they use case folding as their method of normalization in the context of case-insensitive matching. I'm still wading through the confusing way in which Unicode is handling in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984271